# live validation with javascript - onchange only triggered once

Tags: javascript, html, validation, onchange

So I'm just testing something with js, basically the number in the first input has to be bigger than the number in the second input for the submit button to be activated.

The button get's disabled just right, but if I change the number it won't activate again

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<input type='number' id='first' onchange="validateNumber()"/><br>
<input type='number' id='second' onchange="validateNumber()"/><br>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function validateNumber()
{
var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
var second = document.getElementById('second').value;

if(first > second){
document.getElementById('sub').disabled=false;
}else{
document.getElementById('sub').disabled=true;   
}


}
</script>
<input type="submit" id="sub"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: 
The arrows of the number input trigger onchange it seems, that caused the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the `onclick` and `onkeyup` event in order to respond to mouse interactions and to inserts from the clipboard:

http://jsfiddle.net/wzvvN/1

```
<input type='number' id='first' onkeyup="validateNumber()" onclick="validateNumber()" onchange="validateNumber()" />

<input type='number' id='second' onkeyup="validateNumber()" onclick="validateNumber()" onchange="validateNumber()" />
```

Comment: perhaps try with the `onfocus` event instead?

Comment: @ComFreek: `onkeyup()` is what's making it work in that code.

Comment: mmm, sorry but is possible to change the value using the mouse paste.. onchange is needed

Comment: @Hippo `onclick` is needed because you can also change the value with the mouse!

Comment: Hmm...looks like a combination of `onkeyup`, `onclick`, and `onchange` works better. Without the `onchange()`, the callback isn't triggered when you paste using the mouse and switch focus using the `Tab` key.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `onkeyup()`, since `onchange()` gets called only when you switch focus to another element.

Also, your function is currently comparing strings. Use parseInt to convert to an integer and then compare. The following code works for me:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type='number' id='first' onkeyup="validateNumber()"/><br>
<input type='number' id='second' onkeyup="validateNumber()"/><br>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function validateNumber()
{
  var first = parseInt(document.getElementById('first').value, 10);
  var second = parseInt(document.getElementById('second').value, 10);

  if(first > second){
    document.getElementById('sub').disabled=false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('sub').disabled=true;   
  }
}
</script>
<input type="submit" id="sub" disabled="disabled" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that doesn't work well with the html5 number input, for onkeyup I'm not getting any response at all

Comment: yup noticed I got an error in there while I tried it and it didn't work because of that

Answer (score 3):

Try binding the onfocus and onblur events to.

```
<input type='number' id='first' onchange="validateNumber()" onfocus="validateNumber()" onblur="validateNumber()"/><br>
<input type='number' id='second' onchange="validateNumber()" onfocus="validateNumber()" onblur="validateNumber()"/><br>
```

Comment: in my case, `onblur` was the best solution, because i wanted to check contents once the input field LOST focus (i.e. user stopped editing).  UPVOTED :)